# GNU General Public License ERROR?

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, gnu

I have developed a program which makes use of serial programming to read and write from serial port and put the values in databases in Ubuntu environment. Lately, I have added few functionality using boost lib to filter the read function  etc. But when I run the program , say after 15-20 mins , I got segmentation fault .
When I check the log file which I have defined in my program I got following lines in it. I have no clue what is all about. Can  someone guide me on that.

> ```
> a copy of the GNU General Public License          along with this
> ```
>
> program; if not, write to the Free
>   Software         Foundation, Inc., 59
>   Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 
>   ","NU General Public License
>   along with this program; if not, write
>   to the Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place,
>   Suite 330, Boston, MA  ","e
>   along with this program; if not, write
>   to the Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place,
>   Suite 330, Boston, MA  ","ram; if not,
>   write to the        Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place,
>   Suite 330, Boston, MA  ","e Free
>   Software           Foundation, Inc.,
>   59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA
>   ","tion, Inc., 59 Temple       Place,
>   Suite 330, Boston, MA  ","ace, Suite
>   330, Boston, MA  ","MA  ","","","
>   ","HUB-ARM   ")

Thanks and regards,
SamPrat.

Comment: I was about to reformat this question until I realized that I don't even know for sure what's part of the question and what's just misguided blockquote formatting.

Comment: You... want us to tell you what's wrong with the program based on a bunch of faulty log lines?

Comment: Seems you have violated the GPL ;P

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams , Hi Abrams, Thanks for quick response ,I just have a confusion that is there is any link of segmentation fault with the message that i got in log files or not?

Comment: [Your system is infected with GPL.](http://www.topology.org/linux/gpl.html)

Comment: To find the location of the bad pointer, try running it with the debugger: `gdb name-of-program`, then `run`. When it fails, type `bt` to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy answer. Your program segfaulted. That means its is no longer working and it can behave badly.

In this case it started to print out a string (probably not properly terminated) and it was continuing to print out the program memory. And you have probably included the GNU GPL license text which is long. The possibility that segfaulted program will print some of these strings is high.

Check your memory allocations, strings etc. You are facing a memory related bug.

Comment: Use valgrind program to trace it. Install valgrind package and then run $ valgrind your_program to see the error.

Comment: Thanks Izap, for the solution. I havnt seen the above mention error but if I have run valgrind and found mysql_init and mysql_close has few issues. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

My guess,

you have are printing/using an unterminated string. and when you come to print it, well it keeps printing every char until it reaches '/0' or SEGFAULT :), the GPL license text just happens to be in the right place.

Comment: seems , it might be the problem, I will try to investigate further and let you guys know about it. Thanks